# use model belongsTo two Ids in laravel for relationship

Tags: laravel

i have two table

```
media and trainingVideo.

training video having two column video_id and second_video_id 

videos store in media table.
 
i want two relationship both video in trainigtable.
```

**//Model**

---

**// trainingModel**

```
public function media()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Media::class, ['video_id', 'second_video']);
    }
```

**// Media model**

```
public function trainingVideos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TrainingVideo::class, 'id');
    }
```

---

```
$a = TrainingVideo::with('media')->get();
```

i want both video in this relationship.
please help me to solved this.

Answer (score 1):

Answer

Syntax:-

```
$model = Model::with('relatedModel', 'relatedModelTwo')->get();
```

So in your case, it can be something like this.

```
$a = TrainingVideo::with('media','trainingVideos')->get();
```

When you dd($a), you should see the related models in the relations array attribute.

To access the relations' properties from there, it is simply

```
$a->media->media_Attribute

$a->trainingVideos->trainingVideos_Attribute
```

Laravel Relationship Doc :- https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

use model belongsTo two Ids in laravel for relationship
https://stackoverflow.com

Eloquent: Relationships - Laravel - The PHP Framework For Web Artisans
https://laravel.com